# Distance from a point to a closed subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $a\in H$ and $H_0$ be a closed subspace of $H$. Is it true that $d(a,H_0)=\max\{\langle u,a\rangle: \|u\|=1,\, u\in H_0^\perp\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can express $a=x+y$ where $y\in H_0$ and $x\in H_0^{\bot}$

The distance $d(a,H_0)=\left\|a-y\right\|=\left\|x\right\|$.

Now, for $u\in H_0^{\bot}$ with $\left\|u\right\|=1$, $\langle a,u\rangle=\langle x,u\rangle\leq\left\|x\right\|\left\|u\right\|=\left\|x\right\|$ by Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Therefore $\left\|x\right\|$ is the maximum you wanted.